# On the dimension of an linear algebraic group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-groups, affine-varieties

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group (a closed subset of $GL(n,K)$, for some algebraically closed field $K$) and define $\dim(G)$ as its dimension as an algebraic variety over $K$.

Is it true that this concept of dimension is independent of the choice of a basis? In other words, is it true that $\dim(G)=\dim(x^{-1}Gx)$ for every $x\in GL(n,K)$?

I think this should be true but I've found no reference to this fact in any basic text on the subject (but maybe I've missed some nice texts). It seems a natural question to me but I fail to see how change of basis is connected with the dimension as an algebraic variety.

Comment: Isn't this simply due to the fact that conjugation by a fixed $x\in\operatorname{GL}(n,K)$ is an algebraic isomorphism?

Comment: @imtrying46 ok, but why is it an algebraic isomorphism?

Comment: Simply put, because $\operatorname{GL}(n,K)$ is an algebraic group, and thus multiplication and inversion are algebraic. For example, if $A=(a_{ij})$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then left multiplication by $A$ is algebraic, corresponding to the ring endomorphism $X_{ij}\mapsto \sum_k A_{ik}X_{kj}$ of $K[(X_{ij})]$.

Comment: @imtrying46 Ok, so far so good. I agree that is an algebraic isomorphism, but then the thing is why dimension is preserved by algebraic isomorphisms. It is probably this my real problem

Comment: Slightly vaguely put, because algebraic isomorphisms preserve everything algebraic. For affine varieties, the dimension is equal to the Krull dimension of the coordinate ring, and Krull dimension certainly is preserved under isomorphism of rings. For a general variety, you may use for example that any open subset of an irreducible space has the same dimension, so it reduces to the affine case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isomorphism is $\Phi\colon G\subseteq GL(n,K)\to x^{-1}Gx\subseteq GL(n,K)$ sending $z\mapsto x^{-1}zx$.

Of course this map (and it's inverse) is a morphism of algebraic because the multiplication on $GL(n,K)$ is a morphism.